# Travis not deploying tagged commit to pypi

Tags: python, git, travis-ci, pypi

I am trying to automate deploying new versions of [ffn](https://github.com/pmorissette/ffn) to pypi using Travis and I am having some trouble.

My error on Travis is

Already up to date!
Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (1a213f6eb49774d3ff7837f5bde5f187ef3e38f1)
PyPI upload failed.
failed to deploy

You can see the issue [here](https://travis-ci.org/pmorissette/ffn/jobs/383934342).

I got it to work for [bt](https://github.com/pmorissette/bt) but I honestly don't why it is working.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You PyPI passwords in [bt](https://github.com/pmorissette/bt/blob/5a8e3b3041a9eb12e1b9aaecce4dc4c239df3239/.travis.yml#L15) and [ffn](https://github.com/pmorissette/ffn/blob/7a42003e3aa57b72e6ddccc12f22bfac0876c9ea/.travis.yml#L16) are the same. I suspect you've copied `bt/.travis.yml` to `ffn/.travis.yml` but didn't reencrypt the password. At Travis every repository has its own key pair to encrypt secrets so even the same PyPI password is encrypted to different encrypted values.

Reenrypt the password for ffn repository, edit `ffn/.travis.yml`, replace encrypted password, save, commit, tag and push.